# SharePoint 2013: Excel Import Issue

Tags: list, excel

I'm importing an excel list with many columns, but one of the columns is unable to be used in a lookup table. The column contains the multiple owners for the main object and sharepoint can't read it for some reason. Every other column can be used for a lookup but this one. I want to use this column to show who owns the object being reference in a documentation list.
Sorry if this is phrased incorrectly, let me know what more info you need.

Comment: You're trying to get the owners using a lookup from another list?

Comment: The list contains information imported from excel. Each Row has the ID, Name, Owner, etc of the specific item. The owner column isn't working in sharepoint. When I want to create a document in the document library I have a lookup to the list that gets the Name, but I can't get a lookup to work for the owner.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an excel issue. Person or group fields can't be retrieved using a lookup. You can get around this by [using code](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/56745/is-it-possible-to-make-a-lookup-column-that-looks-up-person-or-group-type-from), or by making a string copy of the owner field by running a workflow each time the item is changed, and the string can be retrieved using a lookup.

Comment: The problem is, that sharepoint isn't recognizing them as people or groups, it's just multiple lines of text

Comment: Right, you can't import a person/group field from Excel (http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/41297/working-with-data-imported-from-excel-into-a-sharepoint-list). Easiest way to get the owner would be to create a person/group field, go into datasheet view, and copy the single line of text into Owner. This won't work for users who have never logged into your site collection, but there's a workaround; let me know if you need it.

Comment: My list has 7442 entries and each one has 1-6 owners. That is going to be very painful.

Comment: It's just like copying and pasting an entire column in excel. It should only take a couple minutes. I don't know however, off the top of my head, whether it will work for multiple owners.

Comment: What is the work around for those who haven't logged into the site? My site pulls user data from our outlook user database, so everyone in the company is there.

Comment: I create a dummy permissions group that has no one in it, and put all of the users into it. It adds them to the hidden user list for the site collection. (I copy the user column into word, then find and replace `^l` with `;`.)